# Identify common Lists in List and return Distinct Lists in List

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a following List, I need to iterate through the list and see if the list has identical elements in it and return only a unique list. Could anyone please let me know what's wrong with the following code and a proper way to do it?

Also, Linq way to do it, if any?

Expected Solution would be = `{{"a", "b", "c"},{"e", "b", "c" }}`

```
class Program1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string>[] stringLists = new List<string>[3]
            {
                new List<string>(){ "a", "b", "c" },
                new List<string>(){ "e", "b", "c" },
                new List<string>(){ "a", "b", "c" }
            };

        List<List<string>> prt = new List<List<string>>();

        /* I DONT UNDERSTAND WHY THIS IS NOT WORKING !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! */
        foreach (var item in stringLists)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
            {
                if (item == stringLists[i] && (!prt.Contains(item)))
                {
                    prt.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try good old `Distinct` with a *custom* `IEqualityComparer<T>`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

public class SequenceComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> {
  public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y) {
    return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x, y);
  }

  //TODO: Suboptimal HashCode implementation
  public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj) {
    return obj == null
      ? 0 
      : obj.Count(); 
  }
}
```

...

```
var stringLists = new List<string>() {
  new List<string> {"a", "b", "c"},
  new List<string> {"e", "b", "c"},
  new List<string> {"a", "b", "c"} 
};

// All you have to do is to put Distinct
var result = stringLists
  .Distinct(new SequenceComparer<string>())
  .ToList(); // If you want materialization
```

Test:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
  .Select(list => string.Join(", ", list))));
```

Outcome:

```
a, b, c
e, b, c
```

Answer (score 0):

`prt.Contains(item)` expression compares `List`'s with their **reference** not by their elements, so it's a bad choice for determining if two lists are  duplicates.

Try following

```
 var stringLists = new List<string>[3]
 {
    new List<string> {"a", "b", "c"},
    new List<string> {"e", "b", "c"},
    new List<string> {"a", "b", "c"}
 };

 var prt = new List<List<string>>();

 foreach (var item in stringLists)
 {
     if(prt.All(it => it.Count != item.Count || it.Except(item).Any()))
          prt.Add(item);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do union on all the list and than do a distinct.

Something like this, just iterate through the list and union it with last result:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (var list in stringLists)
        {
            result = result.Union(list).ToList();

        }
        result = result.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: List has an inbuild `AddRange()` to add an other IEnumerable<T> into List<T>

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry Bychenko's answer is the way to go.

For your special case and with data that does not contain `,` you could get away with:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var stringLists = new List<List<string>>{
            new List<string> {"a", "b", "c"}, 
            new List<string> {"e", "b", "c"}, 
            new List<string> {"a", "b", "c"}
        };

        var prt = stringLists
            .Select(l => string.Join(",", l))      // make it a string separated by ,
            .Distinct()                            // distinct it using string.Distinct()
            .Select(l => l.Split(',').ToList());   // split it again at , and make it List

        foreach (var p in prt)
        {
            foreach (var c in p)
                Console.WriteLine(c);

            Console.WriteLine();            
        }   
    }
}
```

There is lots of un-needed object creation in this approach - but i *would* work (until your data contains a `,` - then is messes your lists up).

Output:

```
a
b
c

e
b
c
```

Answer (score 0):

Your misunderstanding is that you expect the statement

```
prt.Contains(item)
```

to return `true` when the sequence of strings in `item` already exists in `prt`. However the test internal to `Contains` used to determine this is a reference equality, not a item by item equality. Here is a minimal example to illustrate this:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.Write( (new []{new []{ "a", "b", "c" }}).Contains(new[] { "a", "b", "c" }));
    // Prints false
}
```

You either need to use a deep equals comparer like @Dmitry's answer which creates a digest (hash) of each list and compares the digests, or to do it explicitly, like this code:

```
class Program1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string>[] stringLists = new List<string>[3]
            {
                new List<string>(){ "a", "b", "c" },
                new List<string>(){ "e", "b", "c" },
                new List<string>(){ "a", "b", "c" }
            };

        List<List<string>> prt = new List<List<string>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            bool isDifferentFromAllOthers = true;
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                bool isSameAsThisItem = true;
                for(int item = 0; item < 3; item++)
                {
                    // !!! Here is the explicit item by item string comparison
                    if (stringLists[i][item] != stringLists[j][item])
                    {
                        isSameAsThisItem = false;
                        break;
                    }                   
                }
                if (isSameAsThisItem)
                {
                    isDifferentFromAllOthers = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isDifferentFromAllOthers)
            {
                prt.Add(stringLists[i]);
            }
        }


//        /* I DONT UNDERSTAND WHY THIS IS NOT WORKING !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! */
//        foreach (var item in stringLists)
//        {
//            for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
//            {
//                if (item == stringLists[i] && (!prt.Contains(item)))
//                {
//                    prt.Add(item);
//                }
//            }
//        }
    }
}
```